# Equivalent cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two cypher queries like below:

```
match sg1 = (n:PI)-[:HAS_DEGREE]-(d:Degree { name : "FACP" } ) , sg2=(n:PI)-[:HAS_SPECIALTY]-(s:Specialty {name: "Gastroenterology"}) return sg1,sg2

match sg1 = (s:Specialty {name: "Gastroenterology"})-[:HAS_SPECIALTY]-(n:PI)-[:HAS_DEGREE]-(d:Degree { name : "FACP" } )  return sg1
```

How do I compare them programmably? In general, to achieve the same result, different cypher queries can be used. How do I know if two queries actually produce the same result without comparing directly the output (suppose the set of queries is very large)?

Comment: Are you working on semantically comparing queries in cypher? that's an awesome project. more power to you!

Comment: For simple comparisons you could probably use EXPLAIN, but queries that produce the same result with a different plan is a bit more complicated

Comment: @jose_bacoy I have ground-truth queries and generated queries, and I want to check if they are equivalent. So yes, semantic comparison

Comment: @TomažBratanič I'm interested in queries with the same semantic but might be slightly different in syntax. What do you mean by EXPLAIN? Can you give a link?

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/   
EXPLAIN
If you want to see the execution plan but not run the statement, prepend your Cypher statement with EXPLAIN. The statement will always return an empty result and make no changes to the database.